# How can I save a page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs

Im playing with Angular Tabs.

I Include one `url` property in my model so I can work with `ng-include="tab.url"` and display a diferent page for each tab. *(is same page just different parameter for tab)*

[image]

But doesnt make sense download the content every time the user click on the tab.

Is there a way I can save the page to save the content locally so only get the page from the server once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the templates directly into [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache). Angular will automatically check this whenever you specify a template src with `ng-include` before attempting to retrieve your template from a remote location.

Comment: work the same with controller action? something like `webSite/Controller/Action/1` and then save another `Action/2` ?